# jQuery strange behavings in checkbox in hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am doing this website here, http://offline.raileisure.com

i am using styled radio and checkboxs.

But when you click book now and the hidden div appears, the one there doesn't work. if i take off the styled class then it does work but i cant work out why it wont work in that hidden div.

Can anyone work it out because I can't

Thanks

Lee

Comment: could you post your code please.

Comment: There's a whole lot of code on that page. It would help a lot if you could reproduce the problem in a much smaller test page.

Comment: But then i am not showing the exact issue and the fix might not work correctly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style applied to it with the 'styled' class simply hides the checkbox (`display: none`) - that would make it entirely unclickable. There are probably a few ways around it I guess - you'll just need to rework the styling.

Comment: but this works on the main page, its just when i have it within that hidden div...

Comment: I just looked at the checkboxes on the main page now and they don't work as you want either. Visually they're working, but the actual `checked` attribute is not changing when you select each checkbox making them redundant anyway. You've got the `<span>` changing on click, but the checkboxes themselves aren't being affected making it all pointless anyway. If you apply the styling to the checkboxes instead of the `<span>` then you'll be sorted. Fixing that should fix your problem in all instances as there'll be no need for hiding elements.

Comment: the checkbox is changed to a span element with live JS. everything works and they are actually radio buttons the other ones.... its just that one in the hidden div.